# Issue for authenticating on parse.com with Twitter

Tags: ios, ios7, twitter, parse-platform

I am trying to use Twitter to authenticate on parse.com in an iOS app.

I have got to the point I have this set in my  application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method.

```
[PFTwitterUtils initializeWithConsumerKey:@"myConsumerKey”
                           consumerSecret:@"myConsumerSecret”];
```

When I tap the twitter button it shows a “Loading …” box for a few seconds and then nothing happens.

What I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I found two details (easy to miss) I needed to modify in the server settings to make things work.

1. The Callback URL field needs to be filled. It appeareatly doesn’
   matter with what as long as it is a well formed URL. Obviously this
   was in my case. I presume the content of the URL sometimes matters.
2. I needed to check “Allow this application to be used to Sign in with
   Twitter”